# Getting an index outside bound of an array in C#

Tags: c#

This program is supposed to show the path of a directory and the directory if its exists then it should also show the files inside with the following extensions (i.e .doc, .pdf, .jpg, .jpeg) but I'm getting an error

> *Index was outside the bounds of the array.

on this line of code

```
string directoryPath = args[0];
```

This is the code in the main function

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

                string directoryPath = args[0];
                string[] filesList, filesListTmp;
                IFileOperation[] opList = { new FileProcNameAfter10(),
                                            new FileProcEnc(),
                                            new FileProcByExt("jpeg"),
                                            new FileProcByExt("jpg"),
                                            new FileProcByExt("doc"),
                                            new FileProcByExt("pdf"),
                                            new FileProcByExt("djvu")
                                            };
                if (Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
                {
                    filesList = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath);
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        filesListTmp = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath);
                        foreach (var elem in Enumerable.Except<string>(filesListTmp, filesList))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(elem);
                            foreach (var op in opList)
                            {
                                if (op.Accept(elem)) op.Process(elem);
                            }
                        }
                        filesList = filesListTmp;
                        if (Console.KeyAvailable == true && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape) break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There is no such directory.");

                }


        }
    }
```

How can I handle this error it seems to be common but it happens id different ways

Comment: are you passing the directory as an argument when you run the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the necessary arguments to the program when running it. You can either do this by running the program from the command line, or else when running Visual Studio by doing the following:

1. Right click on project
2. Properties
3. Debug tag
4. Enter arguments under Start Options -> Command line arguments

Comment: im sorry but im lost what exactly should i type there what arguments should i enter??

Comment: Just the path to the directory, in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want the user to enter a path when the program starts or when they start the program?  If it's the first, then you should add a Console.Read() method that asks for the path.

If it's the latter, then you need to pass the path as an argument when starting the program.  You should also do a check against the args array before reading from it to check that it contains data and that data is a valid path.

Something like:

```
 if(args.Length > 0 && Directory.Exists(args[0]))
 {
   // Do Something.
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to pass the arguments into the program from command line.

like this:

`> yourProgram.exe directoryName`

Also, to avoid such problems in the code,

```
if(args.Length > 0){
  string directoryPath = args[0];
}else{
  //print a help message and exit, or do something like set the 
  //default directoryPath to current directory
}
```